# не работает exec() в php

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, exec

не отрабатывает

```
$command = "libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf /var/www/sjecproject.fvds.ru/frontend/web/generated/img/KP_1573643127.docx --outdir /pdf";
exec($command);
```

srv: Ubuntu.
webSrv: nginx.
php 7.0.
скрипт переводит docx в pdf.

Comment: а если запустить команду в консоли - сработает?

Comment: @Николай Габараев  да, через консоль отрабатывает на ура

Comment: Честно говоря, сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Даже разбираться не стал почему. Решил так - 1. Написал bash-скрипт который принимал переменную с путем до файла. 2. Запускал таким образом - `$res = shell_exec (" /path/to/script.sh '$pathtofolder' ");` 3.Самому скрипту выдал 777 + `+x` (не очень правильно, зато работает =) ) 4. Bash-скрипт может принимать переменные в виде `POS1="$1"` ,а потом использовать ее внутри себя как `$POS1`

Answer (score 0):

exec скорее всего отключен в настройках php. Проверь файл php.ini на такую запись

```
disable_functions = exec
```

Comment: смотрел через phpinfo(). там в графе disable_functions есть такой пункт pcntl_exec(Запустить указанную программу в области текущего процесса) это может быть оно?